# Serve 'file.php' when 'file.css' is requested

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to include PHP in my css files, but I don't want to go site-wide and change the URL. Is it possible, using HTACCESS, to serve `style.php` when `style.css` is requested? Here's what I tried so far:

```
RewriteRule /_css/style.css /_css/style.php
```

Or, better yet: Allow me to keep the extension but have HTACCESS treat it like a PHP file? I'm not very knowledgeable with HTACCESS. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i think you neeed to turn the rewrite engine on `RewriteEngine on`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put this in your file.css at the very top:

```
@import url("file.php");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^_css/([^/]+)\.css$ /_css/$1.php [L]
```

This rule will match every url like `/_css/FILENAME.css` if this is not an existing css file (only matching virtual files). If matched, then rewrites to `/_css/FILENAME.php`

Also, don't forget to enable `mod_rewrite` if not already done

Comment: @Shane Crystal's answer suits you better

Comment: @nl-x No it does not. See the beginning of the question: `I wanted to include PHP in my css files, but I don't want to go site-wide and change the URL`

Comment: @JustinIurman Ah, sorry. Didn't understand what you meant. Thought you didn't want to side-wide change your php settings. So then just take a look at my answer that I just posted. Still no need for htaccess usage.

Answer (score 1):

Url rewriting is needless here. You can call your PHP script this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css/style.php" type="text/css" />
```

This is perfectly valid and does not slow you down.

Comment: But they don't want to go site-wide and change the URL

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your htaccees file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

but it is not recommended because your server may slow.